# Offering offsets for Kotlin's Array<out T>.take(n: Int). Is this good approach for pagination?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Imagine there is a list of 200 items in an Array to put into a RecyclerView, 
this is a huge load and the user probably does not want to wait for the recycler to load every 200 items into it. Is pagination a good approach here? By "pagination" I mean using kotlin's `take(X)`  and increasing X by PAGE_SIZE.

My question is how it is efficient considering all the 200 items are already in memory (but not in recycler)

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in doing it. RecyclerView effectively handles any count of items. It doesn't layout all items, only those shown on the screen plus few off-screen.

Comment: All the x-hundred items are already in memory, but not in the RecyclerView.